# ImageMap creation on Website - Suggestions

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, dictionary

I need some suggestions for an open source solution to creating image maps on my website, and then being able to save the image maps and viewing them on a separate page.

I would also like the ability to save each selected area as a separate image file (jpeg/gif/png).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have come across this:
    http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap
but it is quite old, and not very user friendly. The ability to save the image maps is missing, although it does give the generated code.

Also if it would be easier to create it myself, I would apprevciate tutorials/instructions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with image maps, I'd advice you to look at [ImageMapster JQuery plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/), it can realy help with many image-map manipulation tasks.

And the task of saving image maps with possibility to view them separately is very unussual and hard to implement, I suppose you should think again if you realy need this.

Answer (score 0):

You may just create `DIV` with in image as `background`, then put `float` of have `absolute` position other `div`s inside which will be as link:

```
<div style="width:500px; height:500px; background: #FAFAFA url('someImage.png') center center;">
    <div style="width:250px; height:250px; float:left;" onclick="location.href='http://someurl.com'"></div>
    <div style="width:250px; height:250px; position:absolute; top:20px; right:5px" onclick="location.href='http://someurl.com'"></div>
</div>
```